# If V and W are linear subspaces of $R^n$, then V transversal W means just $V + W = R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, definition, differential-topology, geometric-topology, transversality

If V and W are linear subspaces of $R^n$, then V transversal W means just $V + W = R^n$.

Could anyone give me a hint for this exercise please?

Comment: What is your question? I don't think this is the usual definition for transversal.

Comment: This sounds more like a definition than something in need of proof.

Comment: What's up with all the random tags, but no "linear algebra"?

Comment: This is an exercise in Guillemin & Pollack 1.5.1(b) @EthanBolker

Comment: @RocketMan  This is an exercise in Guillemin & Pollack 1.5.1(b) - differential topology

Comment: @Federico  I have added this tag ..... thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to answer this question, you have to think of $V$ and $W$ as submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$. They intersect transversally if, at every point of their intersection, the sum of their tangent spaces is $\mathbb{R}^n$. But remember that since $V$ and $W$ are *vector spaces*, their tangent spaces at any point are isomorphically just themselves, and we identify them as such. The same goes for the tangent space to $\mathbb{R}^n$ at any point. Since all these identifications *commute* in a sense that can be made precise, there is no conflict if we make all these identifications simultaneously and then think about just the subspaces themselves. Thinking about what this means in the context of transversality, we realize that this is just the condition that $V+W = \mathbb{R}^n$.